# If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form

Tags: html, angular2, angular

В проекте используется Angular 7.
Я получаю ошибку:

> ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
>         control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

HTML код компонента:

```
<form>
    <div class="row m-1">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <span>First name:</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input class="form-control"
                   [(ngModel)]="user.firstName"
                   placeholder="First name"
            >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row m-1">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <span>Last name:</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input class="form-control"
                   [(ngModel)]="user.lastName"
                   placeholder="Last name"
            >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row m-1">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <span>Email:</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input class="form-control"
                   [(ngModel)]="user.email"
                   placeholder="email"
            >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row m-1">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <span>Password:</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input class="form-control"
                   [(ngModel)]="user.password"
                   placeholder="Password"
            >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row m-1">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="register()">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь 2 варианта решения проблемы.

Первый - всем `input` узлам добавить атрибут `name`:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" name="firstName">
```

Второй - использовать то, что советует компилятор:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }">
```

Comment: А есть разница, когда лучше использовать первый способ, а когда второй?

Comment: нет, никакой разницы, разве что если `standalone === true` - директива `NgModel` будет знать что у этой директивы нет родителя

Comment: хм, мне кажется первый вариант обязателен для отправки запроса через форму.. Но для angular оба варианта ни на что не влияют.

Comment: я к сожалению ни разу не видел за последние 3 года чтоб запрос отправляли без js ;) а вообще используйте реактивные формы, чтобы не было танцев с `ngModel`

Comment: спасибо за совет, прямо сейчас посмотрю что это такое)